# "subscript out of bounds" on character vector

Tags: r, sapply, strsplit

I have a vector "nameAlpha" such as c("Mark Twain", "Phil Hall", "Michael P. O'Connor", " ",...). I want to pass each first name to another vector "nameAlpha_first". I run this

```
nameAlpha_first <- sapply(strsplit(nameAlpha, "\\s+"), "[[", 1)
```

But I get

```
Error in FUN(X[[12L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
```

Could it be because few elements of the vector are empty?
How I move to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume we define and preprocess a character vector as such:

```
nameAlpha<-c("Mark Twain", NA, "Phil Hall", 
             "Michael P. O'Connor", " ", "", NA, "John")
nameAlpha[which(nchar(nameAlpha)<2)]<-NA
```

You should write

```
sapply(strsplit(nameAlpha, "\\s+"), head, n=1)
```

And it will work. If you want the last name you can do

```
sapply(strsplit(nameAlpha, "\\s+"), tail, n=1)
```

which will provide you with the vector of last names.

Comment: Great! Can you explain? Was the problem the missing value?

Comment: Yes the problem is the missing value. Because it does not have an element 1. :) In principle I would preprocess your character vector and make sure that " ", "" is set to NA instead.

Comment: And one should I move on to parse the second name? `sapply(strsplit(nameAlpha, "\\s+"), head, n=2)` doesn't work as I would have expected...

Comment: Actually the output is a list not a vector. I had to unlist with `nameAlpha_head <- unlist(nameAlpha_head)[2*(1:length(nameAlpha))-1]` and
`nameAlpha_tail <- unlist(nameAlpha_tail)[2*(1:length(nameAlpha))]`